# Blog engine that is multiblog capable and (optionally) has a Debian package?

Tags: debian, blogs, package

I am sharing a Debian server with a friend, and we host multiple wordpress blogs on the server. The multiblog mechanism for Wordpress provided by Debian doesn't take care of having multiple "content" directories, though. As a result, we can not use images in out blogs at the moment.

I am looking for recommendations for fixing the problem, or alternative blog engines that do a better job with multiple blogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a multiblog-capable version of Wordpress called [Wordpress MU](http://mu.wordpress.org/) you might want to check out.